# The SDL Tridion Reference Implementation Released!

Tags: discussion

The SDL Tridion Reference Implementation has been released and announced on [SDL Tridion World](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2013/reference_implementation.aspx).

Per Bart Koopman, the [SDL Tridion Reference Implementation](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2013/reference_implementation.aspx) is "an MVC web application (v1.0 is released as ASP.NET MVC 5), with CD side Templating. It uses DD4T to serialize the data from the Content Manager and is further designed to keep the web application independent of its "Content Provider."

Learn more:

- [Description](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2013/reference_implementation.aspx)
- [Download](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/reference_implementation.aspx)
- [Sources on github](https://github.com/bkoopman/tri/)
- [Sample website with the whitelabel HTML design](http://bkoopman.github.io/tri/)

Congratulations to Bart, Will Price and everyone that worked on (and sponsored) this reference implementation! Questions about it are welcome on Tridion Stack Exchange.

*Feel free to post additional information, things you might try or want to share about it, or other acknowledgements in "answers" to this Meta question (or edit this post).*

If you are looking for reporting issues or enhancement requests, you can do so on the open source project https://github.com/bkoopman/tri/issues

Comment: I added a link to the full sources on github and a sample of the whitelabel HTML design website

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have enough points to add more than two links. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Nice work, just had a brief look through the code on Github

Quick question, more ASP.NET I guess but I notice opted not to use a SiteMap provider for navigation - was there a specific reason for that or just personal preference?

Comment: Bart, Will, and several others that worked on it could chime in, but I suspect it's related to Sitemaps.org (mentioned in the [docs](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-7339801D-4D95-46B1-8EBC-4000FE282580)). But this might be a better question for the regular TRex Q&A. :-)

Comment: Oh and maybe .NET SiteMap provider support is worth adding to the wish list. I'll +1 to this and others can vote for interesting feedback.

Comment: No special reason. Navigation is based around a JSON 'page' published to the broker (you can also access it with the URL /navigation.json). What you do with this data is up to you. Implementing it via a Navigation controller and views matched well with the way we manage most page elements (as CPs on a page/include page which get rendered by sub controller actions)

Comment: Oh and the reason we use JSON instead of XML for navigation (and other resources/configuration) is to ready for clientside (browser) based rendering, which will be included in future releases

Answer (score 2):

Two additional modules for STRI v1.0.1 were made available just recently:

- [SmartTarget module](https://github.com/jsuurd/tri/tree/feature/smarttarget-module)
- [Media Manager module](https://github.com/jsuurd/tri/tree/feature/mediamanager-module)